# SSH from local Ubuntu laptop to Windows host usinng Remote-SSH VScode

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote-ssh

Can someone help me with the steps to connect my Ubuntu local laptop to a remote Windows 10 host with WSL using Remote -SSH extension vscode?

I tried to find a tutorial but couldn't.

Comment: Do you want to connect your remote pc from locally?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question properly. But, my local computer and the remote desktop are located on two different networks.

Comment: You can use ubuntu remmina.